# CodeIgniter PHP - Access Value in json object

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

i have trouble to get the value in a json object by his name.

items = [Object,Object,Object,Object]

inside of each Object i have my Key => Value.

```
 $http.get($URL, {
            params: {items: items}
        })
        .then(function (response) {


        })
```

**PHP:**

```
$ITEMS = $_GET["items"];
$obj = json_decode($ITEMS);
foreach($obj as $sItem) 
        {
            echo $sItem->CODE;
        }
```

what i doing wrong?~

Error message is this: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: And what is wrong?

Comment: Error message is this: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: What is print_r($obj) showing? Are there objects with CODE ?

Comment: paste the `$ITEMS` here.

Comment: Items:    {"CODE":"10002"}stdClass Object
(
    [CODE] => 10002
)

Comment: @user2232273 this is `$ITEMS`?

Comment: @AgamBanga_ have update the items.. i don´t know why the code is the same when in the parameter request there are differente